# http tp https forward some requests in haproxy

Tags: haproxy

Currently all traffic is coming to backend servers, which is running on port 80. However we want to redirect some pages to https. This means that whenever the customer hits on login page, logout page present in the website. It should be redirected to https.

When a customer hits on the login button it redirect to https but using haproxy it doesn't work.
https://XXXXXXXX.com/customer/account/login/

We have already installed ssl in both the servers.

However, redirection is not working from http to https.

Please suggest what I should try.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to use HAproxy to terminate the SSL and talk to the backend servers via HTTP rather than having both HAproxy and the webserver doing SSL.

There is a good SSL setup tutorial here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-ssl-termination-with-haproxy-on-ubuntu-14-04